# Melted plastic junction box on my gas stove

Tags: wiring

Fireplace was working fine then not. Opened up front and found melted junction box. Could it just be a bad connection inside?

Comment: Need a lot more info. Is the fireplace electric, gas, wood-burning? Pictures of the box location and interior are needed. Turn off power before taking interior pix of the wiring.

Comment: It is one reason(common but only one).  Picture of junction box and fireplace and wires in your question will be nice, plus what HoneyDo asked.

Comment: I have not seen a bad connection melt a box, I have seen receptacles go up in smoke but to tell the truth I don’t remember just a j box having more than melted wire nuts and those were the big blue gray with 6 or 8 awg wire just because a wire nut will fit doesn't mean it should but I doubt you had a motor that large. I would guess a combination of ambient heat and a bad connection could do it was there any char on the plastic or insulation? The Romex is rated at 90c but I am not sure that a plastic box can handle that same amount and they make special wire nuts hightemp usually w fixture wire

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is a "gas stove" a cooking appliance or heating appliance? You say "stove" in the question title, but "fireplace" in the question body. Please [edit] your question to clarify. You can add the pics requested while you're doing that.

Comment: if you think about it, a bad connection is about the only thing that can melt a box.

Comment: @dandavis, I have never observed a j box melting down, yes a hot wire melted the clamp but melted a box? I would say the stove/ fireplace was more likely to be the cause. And yes I have installed many receptacles for both stoves and fireplaces a plastic box is ok for zero clearance but we don’t have enough info to say it was a bad connection but as I said I have not seen this. I have seen enough heat to melt a wire nut but a box , naw it would take a larger Motor that could even be in a plastic box especially in a residential occupancy.